# Getting Servlet: "AxisServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application java.lang.StackOverflowError in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, stack-overflow, apache-axis, weblogic12c

I am getting below error while deploying application on WLS 12c

```
<Jun 8, 2020 11:02:03,120 AM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "AxisServlet" failed to 
preload on startup in Web application: "MyApplication1.0.war".
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:601)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:626)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
 <Jun 8, 2020 11:02:08,698 AM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state 
to true for the application "MyApplication1.0".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
 Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:601)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:626)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Below is my project structure
[image]

Same project is working fine with Weblogic 11G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve issue.
For people having similar issue.
Add weblogic.xml with following content in  tag.

```
<container-descriptor>
       <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

This step will remove stackoverflow error.
Later you might get some dependency error which can be resolved as required.